# How do you query the Throughput setting for Azure CosmosDB databases and containers?

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

I am working to create Cost management scripts setting primarily CosmosDB database RUs in our CI process using PowerShell.

The current code works for creating new databases and setting RUs

```
$resourceGroupName = "rg-01"
$accountName = "cosmos-01"
$databaseName = "db1"
$resourceName = $accountName + "/sql/" + $databaseName
$DataBaseProperties = @{
    "resource"=@{ "id"=$databaseName };
    "options"=@{ "Throughput"="500" }
}
New-AzureRMResource -ResourceType "Microsoft.DocumentDb/databaseAccounts/apis/databases" `
    -ApiVersion "2015-04-08" -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName `
    -Name $resourceName -PropertyObject $DataBaseProperties -Force
```

Containers are then created with:

```
$containerName = "container1"
$resourceName = $accountName + "/sql/" + $databaseName + "/" + $containerName

$ContainerProperties = @{
    "resource"=@{
        "id"=$containerName; 
        "partitionKey"=@{
            "paths"=@("/CompanyName"); 
            "kind"="Hash"
        }
    }; 
    "options"=@{}
} 
New-AzureRMResource -ResourceType "Microsoft.DocumentDb/databaseAccounts/apis/databases/containers" `
    -ApiVersion "2015-04-08" -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName `
    -Name $resourceName -PropertyObject $ContainerProperties -Force
```

I want to be able to query the current RU throughput setting before making changes but am not sure how to request and/or navigate the -PropertyObject.

We are using CosmosDB to Cache configuration values and large returned json objects, both of which can be recreated as needed. We are currently working to set minimum allowed default values on startup via .NetCore code - but also need to be able to adjust for higher values as Production requires.

Powershell updates are extremely slow, so I am looking to eliminate updates during CI where not required. I am currently using the following code to set static values - which will error if additional containers are added and static RUs are too low for the new quantity of containers. I am looking to first query the value, then proceed with changes if necessary.

```
$resourceGroupName = "RG-01"
$accountName = "cosmos-01"
$updateResource = "database" # or "container"
#$updateResource = "container"
Write-Warning "Set Cache Throughput"
$throughput = 1700
$databaseName = "db1"
$properties = @{
    "resource"=@{"throughput"=$throughput}
}
$databaseResourceName = $accountName + "/sql/" + $databaseName + "/throughput"
Set-AzureRMResource -ResourceType "Microsoft.DocumentDb/databaseAccounts/apis/databases/settings" -ApiVersion "2015-04-08" -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $databaseResourceName -PropertyObject $properties -Force
Write-Warning "Set DB Throughput"
$throughput = 500
$databaseName = "flight"
$properties = @{
    "resource"=@{"throughput"=$throughput}
}
$databaseResourceName = $accountName + "/sql/" + $databaseName + "/throughput"
Set-AzureRMResource -ResourceType "Microsoft.DocumentDb/databaseAccounts/apis/databases/settings" -ApiVersion "2015-04-08" -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $databaseResourceName -PropertyObject $properties -Force
```

I would like create to create a get-cosmosDatabaseThroughput function returning the current database throughput. If database throughput is not set, then an error should be returned.

Answer (score 0):

Using Azure CLI , you should be able to read the existing throughput for a given database and container with in CosmosDB account.

[image]

Additional Documentation reference -

[Scale Azure CosmosDB container Throughput using Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/azure/cosmos-db/scripts/scale-collection-throughput-cli#code-try-0)
[PowerShell Module for working with AzureCosmosDB](https://github.com/PlagueHO/CosmosDB#working-with-offers)

Hope this helps